# An odd result from a passed function to a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-state

So i'm having an issue understanding the difference in the manner I make a function call to a prop I passed to a child component.

```
onClick(id)   {
    console.log(id)
}

<div className="card" onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.state.id)}>
```

v.s.

```
<div className="card" onClick={this.props.onClick(this.state.id)}>
```

The first works as expected and gives me the id of the components state when it is clicked. The second one upon loads prints all of the id's for every component before I even get a chance to click on them. What am I missing? onClick is onClick, why is that return statement so important. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling onClick as

```
   onClick={this.props.onClick(this.state.id)}
```

So change to

```
  onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.state.id)}
```

This will prevent getting event handler function called automatically. With the above change the onClick event handler function gets called only when you click

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` in `<div>` expects a function, which is what you give at #1 (called arrow function).

At #2 you give result of executing `this.props.onClick(this.state.id)` which is void.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` needs to be passed a function.

Your first example passes `onClick` a function that calls `this.props.onClick(this.state.id)` when it runs and works properly.

Your second example passes `onClick` *the result of evaluating `this.props.onClick(this.state.id)`* which is why all of the id's are printed immediately when the component loads.  I'm guessing that nothing is returned from calling `this.props.onClick(this.state.id)` so `onClick` has nothing to call when the `div` does get clicked.